# Should I keep sysfs file open for extended period of time?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sysfs

On the device I'm working on, I can write to `/sys/class/leds` to turn a led light on/off. Can I keep the file open in my code and only close when the process exits, or should I only open the file when I need to write to it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There seems to be no harm in doing so.

I tried the following in first shell

```
#tailf /sys/class/leds/mmc0\:\:/brightness
```

And in second shell, tried the same thing.

```
#tailf /sys/class/leds/mmc0\:\:/brightness
```

This experiment is just to show that, at no point opening(tailf) from another process(second shell) was affected by a previous open(tailf) in the first shell.

Comment: Just keep one file open for a longer time (`tail -f`).

Comment: @subin I beg to differ from the point that sysfs entry will be cached. sysfs entries are in ram like a ramfs/tmpfs. There is no disk cache like in the case of actual disks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at tools/thermal/tmon/sysfs.c in Linux kernel source, all the functions use an open->read/write->close. Especially when using standard C library functions like fread/fwrite, the buffering can cause problems. Or you can use fflush() after each write. I would still prefer opening and closing it for each write as sysfs entries are not disk based and can change in runtime. Especially if they correspond to hotpluggable devices.

Comment: Thank to for pointing out the catching issue when using fwrite.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best practice to open and close the file descriptor (fopen) every time. If you will always keep your sysfs open; then it will hold that particular amount of memory till the end.